# Nesting Handlebars 'lookup' with an 'if'

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper

This is a Q&A on whether it is possible to nest the Handlebars `lookup` helper with `if` block helper and if not, are there any alternative solutions to it?

Example scenario below, where we need to check whether the items in 'arrayOne' exist in 'arrayTwo'.

```
{{#each arrayOne}}
    {{#if lookup ../arrayTwo @index}}
      {{this}} - This arrayOne item is present in arrayTwo
    {{else}}
      {{this}} - This arrayOne item is NOT present in arrayTwo
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'No' as the Handlebars syntax won't permit to nest the `if` block helper with `lookup` helper.

The solution is to create a custom helper(`isItemExist`) to check whether the item in 'arrayOne' exist in the 'arrayTwo',

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("isItemExist", function(array, value, options) {
  return value < array.length ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
});
```

And the template would be,

```
{{#each arrayOne}}
  {{#isItemExist ../arrayTwo @index}}
    {{this}} - This arrayOne item is present in arrayTwo
  {{else}}
    {{this}} - This arrayOne item is NOT present in arrayTwo
  {{/isItemExist}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works using version 4.3: {{#if (lookup ./arrayTwo @index)}}