# How to make an inline `if` condition in handlebars partials?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a partial like

```
{{> form/my-form value=form.value.someValue}}
```

I want to send `someValue` to `my-form` only if a condition is `true`. Something like

```
{{> form/my-form value={{#if (condition)}}form.value.someValue{{/if}}}}
```

But this syntax seems to be wrong.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Why not check the condition outside the partial than within? `{{#if condition}}
  {{> form/my-form value=form.value.someValue}}
{{/if}}`

Comment: Because the form should be called anyway. But the parameter can change depending on the condition. In your example if the condition is false then the form will not be called at all

Comment: :) You can use the Handlebars `else` condition too. `{{#if condition}} {{> form/my-form value=form.value.someValue}} {{else}} {{> form/my-form}} {{/if}}`

Comment: Then it will be ugly. Imagine that there are more parameters and only one depends on the condition. And then imagine that there are more partials with similar parameters but different form. I will need to duplicate the same code. I think it will look very ugly

Comment: I believe in that case you need to handle the condition within the partial as Handlebars syntax won't permit to loop helpers and partials. See my Q/A on a similar scenario - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863603/nesting-handlebars-lookup-with-an-if

Comment: But I don't have a loop. Isn't it possible to refactor the partial I have a partial block and inside of the block pass parameters one by one with some conditions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165631/discussion-between-leqada-and-gibin-ealias).

Comment: @LEQADA any luck with this ? stumbled upon the same issue today ! :(

Comment: @semuzaboi can't remember anymore but I think I had to go with the ugly solution proposed above. Handlebars is not really designed to have any inline logic. I think the best solution is not to use handlebars at all.

Comment: @LEQADA .. Ah ok :( thanks for the heads up ! Let me investigate a little further and get back